# Is it possible to set affinity with sched_setaffinity in Android?

Tags: c, multithreading, android-ndk, multicore

Is it possible to set CPU affinity in native C code compiled with the Android NDK? Since the system is using a Linux kernel, it should be possible to use the sched_setaffinity/sched_getaffinity functions, but when I compile with the NDK, I get errors complaining that the cpu_set_t type is unknown (which is used as an argument to the functions). Is there any other way to accomplish this? When I compile with CodeSourcerys ARM compiler (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc) this does not seem to be a problem, so the system obviously supports the required syscalls.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following code works well with NDK r5 or newer:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void setCurrentThreadAffinityMask(int mask)
{
    int err, syscallres;
    pid_t pid = gettid();
    syscallres = syscall(__NR_sched_setaffinity, pid, sizeof(mask), &mask);
    if (syscallres)
    {
        err = errno;
        LOGE("Error in the syscall setaffinity: mask=%d=0x%x err=%d=0x%x", mask, mask, err, err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! I get some complaints about implicit declaration of gettid(), but even if I include sys/types.h (which should be the correct file), I cannot get the compiler to stop complaining. Any ideas?

Comment: I think there should be `unistd.h` instead of `pthread.h`. There too many includes in my project and I'm not sure which are required for this function.

Comment: @Andrey Kamaev: Hi, I m trying to use your function. What is the input mask value ?

Comment: for more on setting the mask see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319725/android-set-thread-affinity

Answer (score 0):

For `cpu_set_t`, I was able to compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE=1` option for Android NDK.