# Android set thread affinity

Tags: android, c, multithreading, android-ndk, multicore

Following the answer from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467848/is-it-possible-to-set-affinity-with-sched-setaffinity-in-android) how do I create the proper 
integer for mask?

I made some googling and the everything I found uses `CPU_SET` macro from `sched.h` but it operates on `cpu_set_t` structures which are undefined when using NDK. When try using `CPU_SET` linker gives me undefined reference error (even though I link against pthread).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, in the end I found some version which was taken directly from `sched.h`. Im posting this here if anyone has the same problem and doesn't want to spend the time searching for it. This is quite useful.

```
#define CPU_SETSIZE 1024
#define __NCPUBITS  (8 * sizeof (unsigned long))
typedef struct
{
   unsigned long __bits[CPU_SETSIZE / __NCPUBITS];
} cpu_set_t;

#define CPU_SET(cpu, cpusetp) \
  ((cpusetp)->__bits[(cpu)/__NCPUBITS] |= (1UL << ((cpu) % __NCPUBITS)))
#define CPU_ZERO(cpusetp) \
  memset((cpusetp), 0, sizeof(cpu_set_t))
```

This works well when the parameter type in the original `setCurrentThreadAffinityMask` (from the post mentioned in the question) is simply replaced with `cpu_set_t`.

Comment: Apparently Bionic has support for `cpu_set_t` in [sched.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/include/sched.h), but the NDK headers have that section rippes out. I wonder how the folks at Google think, if they mangle  Bionic while packaging it with the NDK (both developed and maintained by Google).

Comment: @Samveen they probably don't want to expose all the APIs to NDK applications, for reasons

Answer (score 5):

I would like to pay your attention that function from link in the first post doesn't set the thread cpu affinity. It suits to set the process cpu affinity. Of course, if you have one thread in your application it works well but it is wrong for several threads. Check up sched_setaffinity() description for example [on http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Is this meant as a reply, and if so, to who?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add comments on comments. So i left my comment here.

Answer (score 2):

Try add this before your include `<sched.h>`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```