# Thread affinity in Android with C program

Tags: android, c, linux, multithreading

I have strange problems with thread affinity. I have created a program in C:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
               do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)


#define NANOS 1000000000LL
#define SIZE 1000

void* mesaureTime(void *cpu)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    int s;
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    struct timespec start, end;
    long elapsed;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(*(int *) cpu, &cpuset); 
    s = pthread_setaffinity_np(id, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset); 
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_setaffinity_np");

    if(pthread_equal(id,tid[0]))
        printf("Realizando test...\n");    

    while(i<SIZE){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    // Do some calculation.  
    factorial(150000);      
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    arrayTimes[i] = elapsed;
    elapsed = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec + (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*NANOS;      
    i++;    
    }   
    printf("Finished\n");
    return 0;
}


int factorial(int a){ 

    if (a==1){
            return 1;               
    }else{
        a=a*factorial(a-1);
    }
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int err, result;    
    int *cpu_pointer;
    int cpu = atoi(argv[1]);
    cpu_pointer = &cpu;

    err = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, mesaureTime, (void *) cpu_pointer);

    if (err != 0)
        printf("can't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
    else
       printf("Hilo de test creado satisfactoriamente\n"); 
    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    printf("\n Finalizado el test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This code works well in a Dual Core Intel CPU with Ubuntu, but when I have compiled it with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and I have executed in my Android devices (Nexus 4, Nexus 5 and S4), the program can't assign the thread in CPU 2, CPU 3 or CPU 4, it has only worked in CPU 1. The pthread_setaffinity_np function always returns an error (invalid argument) with CPU 2, 3 or 4.

I have read some questions here [Is it possible to set affinity with sched_setaffinity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467848/is-it-possible-to-set-affinity-with-sched-setaffinity-in-android) and [Android set thread affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319725/android-set-thread-affinity). I have tried it but I have obtain the same result.

Comment: Most likely your kernel doesn't permit user space programs amend affinity. In this case you will need driver to remove `PF_NO_SETAFFINITY` flag from your process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I do this in my process?

Answer (score 0):

The following description from the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) about this error:

```
   EINVAL (pthread_setaffinity_np()) cpuset specified a CPU that was
          outside the set supported by the kernel.  (The kernel
          configuration option CONFIG_NR_CPUS defines the range of the
          set supported by the kernel data type used to represent CPU
          sets.)
```

So it looks like your current kernel has been configured/built with CONFIG_NR_CPUS = 1. This seems to be reason your program is not able to set affinity to your threads to run on other core of your machine.

You may have recompile your kernel to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked the default options when you compile the nexus 5 kernel, and it has the next: "Maximum number of CPUS = 4" and "Multi-core scheduler support" enabled, so the problem isn't here.